# Why is the magnetic moment of a proton weaker than the electron?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, magnetic-moment

I know that the nucleus of an atom does not contribute to the magnetization of an atom or material, and that the magnetic moments of protons are much weaker than electrons.  Why is the magnetic moment of a proton weaker than the electron?

Note: I know that electrons don't actually spin (they're described by wave functions).

Comment: Lazy semi-classical answer: they have the same angular momentum, and the proton is much heavier, so it has a much lower classical angular velocity.

Comment: Yes, but I was hoping for some quantum mechanical explanation.  Thanks though!

Comment: The quantum mechanical answer will come out roughly the same with a lot more work, fwiw.

Comment: So in the end, it's all about the mass?

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of details in there, but ultimately, you will get a result that depends on the mass and the intrinsic spin.  It will be close to the classical picture, but will have some different factors out front.

Comment: I see.  If you know of any good links discussing this in more detail that would be appreciated.  If not, that's cool.

Comment: Any QFT book will cover this.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer You said "so it has a much lower classical angular velocity". I think you meant "classical velocity" other than "classical angular velocity" as angular velocity ($\omega$) is the same for electron and for the proton in the classical hydrogen atom.

Comment: @verdelite, the "spin angular velocity" is the same?  They both have spin angular momentum $\hbar/2$, and many orders of magnitude difference in their mass (plus, the proton isn't a point particle, so its "moment of inertia" would be higher per unit mass), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuclear magnetic moment is given by $\vec{m_N}=g_N\mu_N\vec{I}$, where $\vec{I}$ is a spin of nucleus, $g_N$ is $g$-factor and $\mu_N=\frac{e\hbar}{2m_p}$ is a nuclear magneton.

Orbital magnetic moment of electron is given by $\vec{m}=-\mu_B\vec{l}$, where $\vec{l}$ is a angular momentum (more precisely - operator of angular momentum) and $\mu_B=\frac{e\hbar}{2m_e}$ is a Bohr magneton.

For proton $\langle\vec{m}_N\rangle\approx 2.793\mu_N $.

Hence ratio $\frac{\langle\vec{m}\rangle}{\langle\vec{m}_N\rangle}\approx \frac{\mu_B}{\mu_N}\approx \frac{2000}{2.793}\approx700$.